# filter using lambda with if condition

Tags: python

```
friends_filter = ["Osama", "Wessam", "Amal", "Essam", "Gamal", "Othman"]
namess = filter(lambda names: names if names[-1].lower() == 'm', friends_filter)
for name in namess:
    print(name)
```

why it gives me error (syntax error) before list name

Comment: If you want to filter in strings ending with m, your predicate function should be `lambda name: name[-1].lower() == 'm'`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a Syntax error because you need an else statement for your inline if. but you don't have to use an inline if in your lambda expression
 `if names[-1].lower() == 'm' else None`

Comment: Not true, as the other answer proves.

Answer (score 2):

The predicate only has to return the result of the comparison, not the value itself.

```
friends_filter = ["Osama", "Wessam", "Amal", "Essam", "Gamal", "Othman"]
namess = filter(lambda names: names[-1].lower() == 'm', friends_filter)
for name in namess:
    print(name)
```